# Optimizing CSS Selector

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have a css selector as below which is really lengthy and definitely not suggested to use (** I think so):

```
#moveable_content_User\Depart\Worklist > div > div > div > div.outer.tbody > div > table > tbody > tr
```

Please let me know how can I trim this css? I've tried searching for this, but all I'm getting is some tutorial. So please help

Comment: It depends on the html. You should add it.

Comment: Couldn't get you, could you please elaborate it bit more?

Comment: How can we help you to find another selector without knowing how the html looks like?

Comment: You can't optimize this selector without fundamentally changing its meaning unless we know what assumptions we can make about your HTML. If you don't understand what I just said, then just take it that there's nothing wrong with your selector as it is. You say it's "definitely" not suggested to use, but you don't seem certain of that yourself. So don't worry about it.

Comment: Clever reply Mr. Expert BoltClock... I'll try to share html

Answer (score 0):

In this context, considering there are no other tables inside the parent element.

```
#moveable_content_User\Depart\Worklist table tr
```